# Seized clothing drawers in oak chest

Tags: wood

Okay here is my problem.I have an antique oak 5 drawer chest. I have removed the top 2 drawers with some difficulty a while back.The bottom 3 drawers have seized shut and I really need access to the clothes. It is like the wood has expanded.It use to function well for years.I had to pound on the inside of the second drawer to remove it with a hammer. I keep it in an unheated bedroom.I read on here I might need a dehumidifier. Is there a fix that is less expensive?

Answer (score 4):

In heating season, you could move it to a heated room or put the heat back on in the room that it is in, which would have the same effect as a dehumidifier, without needing to buy one.

Once you get the drawers out, you can plane or sand them down a bit where they have been sticking to prevent a recurrence. A bit of wax on the parts that touch may also help.

Comment: Once you get them free, you may discover they are on small wooden runners, which may be easier to trim, or replace once everything shrinks again in spring.

Comment: I am unable to move it to a heated room. It is 4 feet tall by 18 inches deep and 32 inches wide. I don't have central heat and I use the room for storage. I have a rubber mallet I might use from inside the 3rd drawer to remove for access to the clothes in the 4th and so on. If I am able to get the 3rd drawer unstuck. I guess there isn't any easy fix.